# How much faster is `int_fastXX_t` than `int` in practice?

Tags: c, optimization

I'm optimizing a large C project whose integer arithmetic presently uses `int`.  I'm considering switching to `int_fast16_t` (or even `int_fast8_t`) wherever a small integer is sufficient.  This'll be a reasonably big job, so before I set out, I want to be confident that this has the potential to decrease run-time noticeably (> 5–10%) for users running the software on modern PCs.

As this will depend on the compiler and hardware (edited to clarify: this will differ from end-user to end-user -- so it's hard to know how representative benchmarking on my own PC would be), I appreciate that this is something of a "how long's a piece of string" question – but is there a rule of thumb for what sort of order of magnitude of speed-up I might hope to gain?  Are particular categories of operation particularly likely to yield a benefit?

---

Related:

- [What's the difference between "int" and "int_fast16_t"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942107)
- [Why is uint_least16_t faster than uint_fast16_t for multiplication in x86_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116297/)

Comment: *"As this will depend on the compiler and hardware"* Note that you haven't mentioned any of them. Also, more than the types, the algorithms and the possible dedicated hardware (are you taking advantage of SIMD instructions?) are more likely to have much an impact.

Comment: You might be stuck converting a small part of your program and benchmarking before/after.

Comment: The answer is: "impossible to say unless you do it and then do some profiling and measurements".

Comment: I would not expect it to yield any noticeable difference TBH.

Comment: I suspect going from `int` to `int_fast8_t` will reduce performance. It'll save you memory though. They're nothing but aliases to signed/unsigned char or word-size of the hardware.

Comment: If you accessing a large array, using a smaller type may cause fewer cache misses.

Comment: @जलजनक Hm, I would expect that `int_fast8_t` will be as fast as `int` in most cases, as `int` uses the "natural" word size of the processor. It is allowed to be larger, isn't it? -- However, benchmarks need to be run.

Comment: If you need to gain just few percents, this might work. But if you need more, I think there is no way around faster algorithms. It all depends on the application.

Comment: If your code is SIMD-friendly, then using smaller type can drastically speed up the operation since more 8-bit integers fit in a SIMD register than 16-bit or even 32-bit (respectively 2 and 4 times). For non-SIMD code, this is hard to say, it may be slower in some cases with smaller type on x86-64 platforms. `int_fast8_t` is implementation-defined so nobody can say if this type will be faster in practice with the provided informations. If your computation is SIMD-friendly, please consider using fixed-size types like `int8_t`. Otherwise, `int_fast8_t` is fine.

Comment: interesting presentation that discusses this very topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieERUEhs910&t=6s

Comment: Busybee, it should _never_ be slower than int, since int is at least 8 bit, and int8_fast_t should be the fastest 8 bit type. That would mean the compiler is substandard or broken.

Comment: @gnasher729: "Never be slower" isn't possible.  For example, smaller types that fit more array elements into a cache line make code faster as a rule (less memory pressure)... but false sharing is the exception to that rule, where you can lose an order of magnitude of performance because more tasks are contending for ownership of the same cache line.  Even if the optimizer is awesome and knows that in this particular data structure, the smaller data type is worse, `int_fast8_t` is required to be *the same type* everywhere it appears.

Answer (score 0):

int_fast8_t is the fastest type with at least 8 bits. Assuming a reasonable compiler, it’s never slower than int (if it was then the compiler should have used int). int should be the most common type so it should be fast, it’s quite likely that int8_fast_t *is* int. especially since this means there are no conversion between int8_fast_t an int needed. That will be by far the most common case.

On an 8 bit or 16 bit system int8_fast_t may be smaller and faster than int, but likely not much. The opposite on a 64 bit system, where int may be 32 bits and slower (but smaller) than a 64 bit int.

And there’s Jeromes comment: If you need a vector of 8 bit ints, and int8_fast_t is 32 bit, then an SIMD vector of int8_fast_t is *not* what you want. Would be likely as fast as a vector of int, but possibly four times slower than a vector of int8_t.