# What are the pros and cons of int, unsigned int, uint_fastN_t, and int_fastN_t?

Tags: c, performance, integer, micro-optimization

I have a variable and the type does not matter; the possible range will easily fit in any of the aforementioned types. For example a loop counter. Etc.

What are the pros and cons of using:

- `int`
- `unsigned int`
- `int_fastN_t`
- `uint_fastN_t`

***Note to any potential close-voters:** I am not asking which ones to use, because that would be opinion-based, but I am asking, what factors should I consider when choosing one over the other?*

Comment: Related is [How much faster is int_fastXX_t than int in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72060755/how-much-faster-is-int-fastxx-t-than-int-in-practice)

Comment: Also see [uint32_t vs int as a convention for everyday programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20077313/2410359)

Answer (score 3):

***Signed* vs. *Unsigned***

- Prefer *unsigned* types for logical and pattern data manipulation.
- If following a documented algorithm, match its sign-ness should it specify one.
- Use *signed* types for general data manipulation.
- Avoid mixing sign-ness of types in an equation.
- Use `size_t` (an *unsigned* type) for array sizing and indexing.
- Operations with *signed* types readily incur UB [@Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100411/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-int-unsigned-int-uint-fastn-t-and-int-fastn-t/77100574?noredirect=1#comment135928164_77100574) thus *unsigned* types are favored in critical applications.

***Fast* or not**

- Avoid `(u)int_fastN_t` unless certain of the need.  Maybe when a narrow type is needed, yet speed it critical.  They are not worth using on a whim.
- `fast` types oblige documentation to justify it use.
- Never use `...fast..` as a bit-field.
- Wide `(u)int_fastN_t` is rarely useful.
- Portability: `(u)int_fastN_t/(u)int_leastN_t` are always available since C99 and have a slight edge concerning portability versus the *optional*  `(u)intN_t`.
  `int/unsigned` are *always* available since the dawn of C.
- **Keep in mind that *fast* types are a compromise.  *Fast* is not always fastest in all use cases.**

Comment: *Maybe when a narrow type is needed, yet speed it critical.* - In that case you should avoid `uint_fast32_t` because of bad design choices by glibc, which makes `uint_fast32_t` a 64-bit type on x86-64, even though `uint32_t` is the most efficient unsigned type for most things on x86-64.  Multiplication and especially division are slower for 64-bit on some CPUs for example, and of course costs extra machine-code size (REX prefixes).  For local variables that live in registers, 64-bit is sometimes fine, but 32-bit is zero-extended to 64-bit for free in case it's needed as an array index.

Comment: For `int_fast32_t`, maybe they were trying to save the occasional `movsxd` instruction by making it 64-bit, but that makes it useless for arrays and structs where you're looking for a type that's at least 32-bit but doesn't have any big performance potholes.  Wasting twice as much cache footprint and memory bandwidth is really bad.  Again, ok only for local variables, and only if you're not doing division by runtime variables on Intel CPUs before Ice Lake, or multiply on AMD before Zen, or some low-power Intel CPUs.  Just terrible design choices to make all narrow types except `fast8` 64-bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes Useful thoughts that support "Keep in mind that fast types are a compromise. Fast is not always fastest in all use cases."

Comment: Yeah exactly.  That point needs more emphasis, that the library designers might have had the wrong kind of "fast" in mind, or just made a bad choice when the architecture was new and didn't want to make a breaking change later (for code that has `fastN` types as part of their ABI, which I think is not recommended BTW.)

Comment: "Use signed types for general data manipulation." What exactly is data manipulation? Equations should not be signed types unless the result can in theory be negative. There are lots of pitfalls with signed types so avoid them when you can, particularly in mission-critical software and embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some factors to consider to make your choice:

- If the bounds are integer literals, use the classic

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
      ...
  }
  ```

  rationale: the simpler the better.
- if the bounds are variables, use the same type as that of the bound.

  ```
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- if the bounds may exceed the range of `int`, use a larger type: `long` or `int64_t`... using the `int_fastN_t` or `int_leastN_t` makes the code harder to read and will not make a difference on most architectures.

Answer (score 1):

- **`int`**
  This type pretty much only has one single benefit and that is backwards-compatibility of non-critical code where integer limits/sizes do not matter. You should almost never use it, unless you are stuck with some backwards compatibility case with old C90.
- **`unsigned int`**
  Same arguments as with `int` - this type is mostly to be used in old code where integer sizes don't matter. It is slightly more useful though, because it can be regarded as a safe common type to use in expressions that are subject to implicit integer promotion. If you use `unsigned int` or cast an operand to it, then it is no longer subject to integer promotion, default argument promotion and similar. You can also safely use `unsigned int` in bit-wise arithmetic, where `int` should be avoided.

  Furthermore, small integer types like `short`, `signed char` etc are similarly dangerous because they are subject to implicit promotion, potential signedness change due to integer promotion, potential to hide overflows/wrap-around due to promotion, etc etc.
- **`intn_t`** (where *n* corresponds to the word size of the target)
  Compared to `int`, the `intn_t` has the great advantage of being portable and of fixed width. But only if *n* is large enough not to make the operand subject of integer promotion, for example `int32_t` on a 32/64 bit computer.

  `intn_t` also has the great advantage of being guaranteed to be in 2's complement form, which is not guaranteed for `int` (until the release of C23).

  A little detail is that `intn_t` isn't guaranteed to be supported unless the target supports it. This doesn't apply to 99% of all real-world systems, only to some oddball DSP CPUs that have 16 bit bytes.

  Notably `intn_t` should *only* be used where you actually need signed numbers. If you don't need signed numbers then use the `uintn_t` equivalent.
- **`uintn_t`**
  All the same benefits of `intn_t` but with yet another benefit, namely that it is also safe to use for bitwise-arithemtic. Making this the most universal integer type of them all.
- **`int_fastn_t`**
  This is mostly used during manual micro-optimization, where size isn't important but you suspect that a larger integer type would result in faster code. It could also have its uses when writing widely portable code.

  For example if you develop code with arithmetic that needs to be at least 16 bit and should run on both 16 and 32 bit CPUs. Doing the arithmetic on `int16_t` might not be optimal for the 32-bitter because of limited instructions, alignment etc. But if you do the arithmetic on `int_fast16_t` then it will not needlessly burden the 16 bitter as 32 bit arithmetic would have, since the type would still be 16 bits on that target. But at the same time it still allows the 32 bitter to pick a larger type if that gives better performance.

  Another advantage is that `int_fastn_t` is mandatory for *all* C compilers for 2's complement targets, including freestanding implementations (embedded systems, oddball DSP compilers etc).

  The disadvantages vs `intn_t` is that `int_fastn_t` *isn't* fixed width, where exact width matters, and that using `int_fastn_t` enforces a manual speed-over-size optimization which we might normally let the picked compiler options decide.
- **`uint_fastn_t`**

  Same advantages/disadvantages as `int_fastn_t` but is also suitable for bitwise-arithmetic.
- **`int_leastn_t`/`uint_leastn_t`**

  These are oddball types with very specialized use. Basically you say that "I need the variable to be at least *n* bits but other than that you may do as you please". Unlike the `fast` types, this gives the compiler more freedom in picking either size or speed optimizations, or not optimization at all.

  There's not a lot of use for these types save when you need to optimize for size and at the same time be portable across multiple targets. For example in my 16 vs 32 bit CPU example above, the `int_least16_t` would still be 16 bits on the 16 bit CPU, but on the 32 bit CPU the compiler might chose to leave it as 16 bits in case that would give a size benefit.

  For example a 32 bit PowerPC with support for VLE encoding (basically: use 16 bit instructions when possible) might benefit from the `least` types, since you could leave the C code the same, no matter if the machine code uses VLE or not.

---

**Integer picker program**
I hacked together a tl;dr integer picker. Tweak the true/false per #define and let it pick the suitable integer type.

Tested with gcc 13.2 -std=c2x. https://godbolt.org/z/zz9GTf35M

```c
// pick true/false for each of these parameters:
#define CODE_NEEDS_TO_BE_WIDELY_PORTABLE           true
#define CODE_MUST_BE_C90                           false
#define I_NEED_NEGATIVE_NUMBERS                    false
#define I_NEED_BITWISE_ARITHMETIC                  false
#define I_CARE_ABOUT_NUMERICAL_LIMITS              true
#define I_HAVE_SPECIAL_OPTIMIZATION_REQUIREMENTS   false

_Static_assert(!(CODE_NEEDS_TO_BE_WIDELY_PORTABLE && CODE_MUST_BE_C90), 
                "Contradicting requirements. C90 isnt portable.");

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  if(CODE_NEEDS_TO_BE_WIDELY_PORTABLE)
    if(!I_NEED_NEGATIVE_NUMBERS || I_NEED_BITWISE_ARITHMETIC)
      if(!I_HAVE_SPECIAL_OPTIMIZATION_REQUIREMENTS)
        puts("Use uintn_t");
      else
        puts("Use uint_fastn_t/uint_leastn_t depending on the situation.");
    else
      if(!I_HAVE_SPECIAL_OPTIMIZATION_REQUIREMENTS)
        puts("Use intn_t");
      else
        puts("Use uint_fastn_t/uint_leastn_t depending on the situation.");
  else
    if(!I_NEED_NEGATIVE_NUMBERS || I_NEED_BITWISE_ARITHMETIC)
      if(!CODE_MUST_BE_C90 || I_CARE_ABOUT_NUMERICAL_LIMITS)
        puts("Use uintn_t");
      else if(CODE_MUST_BE_C90 && I_CARE_ABOUT_NUMERICAL_LIMITS)
        puts("Use home-brewed type system replicating uintn_t from stdint.h");
      else
        puts("Use unsigned int");
    else
      if(!CODE_MUST_BE_C90 || I_CARE_ABOUT_NUMERICAL_LIMITS)
        puts("Use intn_t");
      else if(CODE_MUST_BE_C90 && I_CARE_ABOUT_NUMERICAL_LIMITS)
        puts("Use home-brewed type system replicating intn_t from stdint.h");
      else
        puts("Use int");
}
```